# Neo4j Batch Inserter error: IllegalStateException

Tags: neo4j, export-to-csv, graph-databases

I am very new to Neo4j. I downloaded Neo4j 2.0 for Windows and I tried to run commands in the command prompt in order to import CSV files into Neo4j. I saved the CSV files as stated on [Max de Marzi's blog](http://maxdemarzi.com/2012/02/28/batch-importer-part-2/). 
Then I executed this line:

```
java -server -Xmx4G -jar target/batch-import-jar-with-dependencies.jar target/graph.db nodes.csv rels.csv
```

But i got this error:

```
Total import time: 3 seconds
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Index users not configured.
    at org.neo4j.batchimport.Importer.importNodes(Importer.java:102)
    at org.neo4j.batchimport.Importer.doImport(Importer.java:210)
    at org.neo4j.batchimport.Importer.main(Importer.java:78)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A significant number of things have changed in 2.0, including support for Labels and changes with indexes. The instructions you are following are too old to be for the 2.0 branch.

Try this: https://github.com/jexp/batch-import/tree/20 
the 20 branch is for neo4j 2.0 and should work for you.

Or, downgrade to 1.9 and try again.